# Why does my game interpret the mouse pointers coordinates wrong

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I have an monogame (2D) game I'm making and when I try to get the mouse coordinates they are wrong. I have no idea what the issue is but here is my code where I get the coordinates:

```
MouseState mouseState;
mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
test = new Tower(TowerTexture, new Vector2(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y));
//test is drawn where mouse pointer is thought to be and it is drawn off
```

Here is the tower drawing code:

```
    foreach (Tower tower in towers)
    {
        tower.Draw(spriteBatch);
    }
```

And here is the draw function for the tower:

```
public virtual void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, center, null, Color.White, rotation,
    origin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
}
```

One more thing is that as the mouse pointer, the real one is closer, to the upper left corner the offset of the supposed mouse coordinates is less but as you go closer and closer to the lower right corner of the screen the supposed mouse coordinates are farther off.
I honestly have no idea what's wrong but any thoughts on what might be wrong would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: the coordinates are wrong...in what way?

Comment: Could you paste code where you draw towers?

Comment: You might want to provide some more information on how the location returned by `mouseState.X` and `mouseState.Y` are "off". According to the documentation the coordinates returned are relative to the upper-left corner of your game window.

Comment: The coordinates are not where the mouse pointer actually is. And i will post that code in a second.

Comment: I also tried making test a different class than a plant and the results were the same

Comment: Yes what i mean by off is that when I draw a sprite at the supposed location of the mouse pointer the sprite is not drawn in the correct place where the mouse pointer really is.

Comment: One notable thing though is that as you move the mouse pointer closer to the upper left corner the offset of the sprite that is drawn at the mouse pointer becomes less and less and as you move it farther away and closer to the lower right corner of the screen the offset of the sprite from the real mouse pointer is larger.

Comment: Have you tried setting the game to fullscreen, and also set the `PrefferedBackBufferWidth and Height` to the same as the monitor's?

Comment: What are mouseState.X and mouseState.Y when the mouse is in the bottom right corner of the window? How bout top left? What should it be? I would suggest printing the value of mouseState.X, mouseState.Y to the debug log, to eliminate any issues that might be in your rendering code.

Comment: x is 1364 and y is 766 when the pointer is in the bottom right corner

Comment: And in the upper-left corner it is 0,0

Comment: The dimensions of the background are 1920 on x and im not sure about y

Comment: @Detinator10, you've asked this question 3 times, and everytime you give the same code. If no one could help you the first two times, you may want to consider adding more code, such as the Update and Initiations of the Towers. Also, I would check everything in my game that could affect the screen resolution, such as `graphicsdevice.PresentationParameters.PreferredBackBufferWidth` and `graphics.IsFullScreen`, and also check the resolution of the computer monitor itself. I highly doubt Mouse.Getstate is returning the wrong values. I'd also try my game on a different computer if I could.

Comment: I checked the resolution of my screen and *coincidentally* the resolution of my screen is as far as the supposed mouse pointer will go. If I move my mouse pointer to the bottom right then the coordinates of the supposed mouse pointer are the resolution of my screen.

Comment: Does anyone know what I can do to fix it? @davidsbro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in response to both this question and your [question on hold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471286/how-can-i-make-it-so-that-the-resolution-of-my-image-is-the-same-as-my-screen?noredirect=1#comment32446874_21471286). To fix this problem, you can scale down your image when you draw it. I'm not quite sure what the value of `center` is, but my guess is that it is a rectangle with its center at the mouse pointer. To scale down the image, try something like this:

```
Rectangle center;

public Tower(Texture2D TowerTexture, Vector2 location)
{
    float scaledown = 10;
    float XOffset = TowerTexture.Width / (2 * scaledown); //get an X and Y offset to center the image in the rectangle
    float YOffset = TowerTexture.Height / (2 * scaledown);
    this.center = new Rectangle(location.X + XOffset, location.Y + YOffset, 
        XOffset * 2, YOffset * 2);
}
```

Then Draw this image like you did previously, using `center` as the destination rectangle. I wrote this code without a compiler or debugging, but I think it should give you a basic idea.
HTH

Comment: When i was talking about image i was referring to thw background

Comment: @Detinator10, you could use something similar to what I put above. Just change the center rectangle for the background to `new Rectangle(0,0,1366, 768)`

Comment: I did that and it worked the only thing is now my enemies spawn off the screen. And also if i played the game wity a different monitor resolution would the game still draw the same?

Comment: I'm not sure why your enemies would spawn offscreen since I don't know the code, but I would try something similar to what I put for spawning the towers. And no, the game would draw differently. However, what you can do instead of `new Rectangle(0, 0, 1366, 768)` is get the resolution of the screen by doing `new Rectangle(0, 0, GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth, GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight)` This will draw the background to whatever the computer's resolution is (if you haven't preset either property and the game's in fullscreen)

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong is that the resolution of my image is bigger than the resolution of my screen.